# Taking the sum of two 1D arrays, creating a third array, and passing it back

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, sum

I've been tasked with taking two one-dimensional arrays, of floating data, adding them element by element to create a third array. I have to pass them specifically to a function addfloat to accomplish this and then pass it back to the main program for display.

Where I'm getting stuck is how to store/reference the ??? = array1+array2. How do I reference the newly created third array back in the main function?

Yes this is for a course I am taking. My online instructor has not been helpful in my understanding of the concept. He just keeps telling me to submit what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addfloat(float [],float []);

int main ()
{
float SLG [10] = {.508,.504,.473,.415,.407,.379,.388,.340,.405,.278};
float OBP [10] = {.434,.327,.425,.342,.314,.270,.328,.348,.327,.306};
float OPS [10];
int j,k,g,n;


addfloat (SLG,OBP);

printf("Their Slugging Percentages (SLG) are:\n");
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
                printf("%.3f, ",SLG[j]);
        }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Their On Base Percentages (OBP) are:\n");
        for (k=0; k<10; k++)
            {
                printf("%.3f, ",OBP[k]);
            }
    /*Place work-around back in here if necessary where I just add the two arrays without     passing it out*/

    printf("\n");
    printf("Their Slugging Percentage (OPS) are:\n");
        for (g=0; g<10; g++)
            {
                printf("%1.3f, ", OPS[g]);
            }
    return 0;
}

void addfloat (float SLG[],float OBP[])
    {
        float OPS [10];
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            OPS[i] = SLG[i]+OBP[i];
        }
return (OPS[]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Its my understanding that an array is just a pointer to the first piece of data in the array.

That's wrong, arrays are arrays, pointers are pointers, and they're not the same. [Read this.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

> How do I reference the newly created third array back in the main function?

Return a dynamically allocated, new array? Pass a third argument to a function? So many ways. E. g.:

```
void add_floats(const float a[], const float b[], float y[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        y[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Call it like:

```
#define COUNT 3

float first[COUNT] = { 1, 2, 3 };
float second[COUNT] = { 4, 5, 6 };
float result[COUNT];

add_floats(first, second, result, COUNT);
```

Comment: AHHH!! I was so close!! Thanks. So if you had to put into words what I was doing wrong, what would it be?

Comment: After looking at it again. I feel like I was telling it to return a value that it wasn't told to look for from the pass back...something like that?

Comment: @starkynuke The first word that comes to my mind is that "you haven't read and learnt that beginners' C tutorial carefully enough" :P More seriously, you were trying to return stuff from a function returning `void`, which is wrong by definition, you were trying to return a local automatic array which causes undefined behavior, etc.